# iOS Amazon S3 SDK: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, memory-management

I'm getting the following error:

```
*** -[S3PutObjectOperation_Internal respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x43c18fd0
```

I don't understand the stack trace from Zombies inspector very well, I'm not sure this is telling me anything I can fix:

```
#   Address Category    Event Type  RefCt   Timestamp   Size    Responsible Library Responsible Caller
0   0xc071f60   S3PutObjectOperation_Internal   Malloc  1   00:14.903.021   48  MyApp   -[S3TransferManager upload:]
1   0xc071f60   S3PutObjectOperation_Internal   Retain  2   00:14.903.032   0   Foundation  ____addOperations_block_invoke_0
2   0xc071f60   S3PutObjectOperation_Internal   Release 1   00:14.903.036   0   MyApp   -[S3TransferManager upload:]
3   0xc071f60   S3PutObjectOperation_Internal   Retain  2   00:14.904.154   0   libsystem_sim_blocks.dylib  _Block_object_assign
4   0xc071f60   S3PutObjectOperation_Internal   Retain  3   00:14.904.163   0   libsystem_sim_blocks.dylib  _Block_object_assign
5   0xc071f60   S3PutObjectOperation_Internal   Release 2   00:14.904.164   0   Foundation  __destroy_helper_block_474
6   0xc071f60   S3PutObjectOperation_Internal   Retain  3   00:14.906.549   0   MyApp   -[S3PutObjectOperation_Internal start]
7   0xc071f60   S3PutObjectOperation_Internal   Release 2   00:14.906.554   0   MyApp   -[S3PutObjectOperation_Internal start]
8   0xc071f60   S3PutObjectOperation_Internal   Release 1   00:14.907.624   0   MyApp   __destroy_helper_block_
9   0xc071f60   S3PutObjectOperation_Internal   Retain  2   00:15.243.299   0   MyApp   -[S3PutObjectOperation_Internal finish]
10  0xc071f60   S3PutObjectOperation_Internal   Retain  3   00:15.243.302   0   MyApp   -[S3PutObjectOperation_Internal finish]
11  0xc071f60   S3PutObjectOperation_Internal   Release 2   00:15.243.307   0   MyApp   -[S3PutObjectOperation_Internal finish]
12  0xc071f60   S3PutObjectOperation_Internal   Release 1   00:15.243.330   0   MyApp   -[S3PutObjectOperation_Internal finish]
13  0xc071f60   S3PutObjectOperation_Internal   Release 0   00:15.244.420   0   Foundation  __release_object_op
14  0xc071f60   S3PutObjectOperation_Internal   Zombie  -1  00:15.386.107   0   MyApp   -[S3Response connection:didSendBodyData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:]
```

This error happens when the application is uploading photos. The Photo object uses  and implements the following methods:

```
-(void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didSendData:(NSInteger)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite
{
  NSLog(@"didSendData called: %d - %d / %d", bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
  self.transferProgress += bytesWritten;
  float p = (float) self.transferProgress / self.uploadSize;
  self.uploadProgress = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:p];
}

-(void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didCompleteWithResponse:(AmazonServiceResponse *)response
{
  NSLog(@"didCompleteWithResponse called.");
}

-(void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
  NSLog(@"didFailWithError called: %@", error);
}
```

As far as I know this is the only point in the app in which the S3 request is talking to any other objects/instances. Any idea what is causing this error?

Comment: where do you call `-upload?` Are you passing a completion block? If so, try passing `[block copy]` instead.

Comment: I see this happening as well. Any suggested solution?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. This is happening when the response from S3 is a 400 because the temporary credentials I use expired. It looks like a bug in the AWS SDK to me, maybe only happening in conjunction with S3TransferManager?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bug in the AWS SDK. I'm not sure where exactly the bug is but it's triggered by request retries if the response was a service exception (and possibly only in conjunction with S3TransferManager).

I didn't want to disable all retries, so I fixed this by forcing no retries for service exceptions. You can do this by using a subclass of AmazonS3Client where you override one method like this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldRetry:(AmazonServiceResponse *)response exception:(NSException *)exception
{
    // There is some kind of bug that is triggered on request retries when S3 requests
    // return an explicit service exception (e.g., auth token expired). In these cases
    // we force no retry to avoid the bug.
    NSException *exceptionHolder = response.exception;
    if(exceptionHolder == nil)
    {
        exceptionHolder = exception;
    }

    if([exceptionHolder isKindOfClass:[AmazonServiceException class]])
    {
        return NO;
    }

    return [super shouldRetry:response exception:exception];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, our app was using an old AWS SDK and this answer fixed the Exception we had after uploading an image/video.